# How to solve error 'Callbacks disabled in gurobi'?

Tags: callback, pyomo, gurobi

Currently I am investigating an MILP in Pyomo with gurobi. I would like to be able to add cuts during the B&B and found that callback functions can be used for this purpose. However, when I try to implement a callback function I get the following error: "callbacks disabled for solver gurobi" (or: callbacks disabled for gurobi_persistent). This error does not seem very common, does someone have any experience with it?

I am quite new to both Pyomo and gurobi.

My code is the following (an example that I found through the Pyomo documentation).

```
from gurobipy import GRB
import pyomo.environ as pe
#from pyomo.core.expr.taylor_series import taylor_series_expansion

m = pe.ConcreteModel()
m.x = pe.Var(bounds=(0, 4))
m.y = pe.Var(within=pe.Integers, bounds=(0, None))
m.obj = pe.Objective(expr=2*m.x + m.y)
m.cons = pe.ConstraintList()  # for the cutting planes

def _add_cut(xval):
    # a function to generate the cut
    m.x.value = xval
    return m.cons.add(m.y >= ((m.x - 2)**2))

_add_cut(0)  # start with 2 cuts at the bounds of x
_add_cut(4)  # this is an arbitrary choice

opt = pe.SolverFactory('gurobi_persistent')
opt.set_instance(m)
#opt.set_gurobi_param('PreCrush', 1)
#opt.set_gurobi_param('LazyConstraints', 1)

def my_callback(cb_m, cb_opt, cb_where):
    if cb_where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
        cb_opt.cbGetSolution(vars=[m.x, m.y])
        if m.y.value < (m.x.value - 2)**2 - 1e-6:
            cb_opt.cbLazy(_add_cut(m.x.value))

opt.set_callback(my_callback)
opt.solve()
assert abs(m.x.value - 1) <= 1e-6
assert abs(m.y.value - 1) <= 1e-6
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been answered by gurobi support. Apparently Pyomo does not allow/implement callbacks.

Comment: Interestingly the example you've posted *is* supported by Pyomo despite what Gurobi support may have suggested. Running your code locally myself I don't get any errors. I can also verify that your callback is being triggered by adding a `print()` statement inside it that is triggered. Could you try adding `assert isinstance(opt, GurobiPersistent)` to ensure you're using the correct Gurobi interface? Also what versions of Python, gurobipy, and Pyomo are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have a new laptop, so I had to reinstall everyting. Interesting enough, it now seems to work.  On both laptops, Python 3.7 is installed and gurobi 8.1.1. the version of Pyomo I previously used is 5.6.6 and the version I currently use is 5.6.9. It could be that this caused the error.

Comment: Great to hear! Yes, this feature was added in 5.6.7 so that would do it ;)